# Why is Promise<any> a valid TS return type?

Tags: typescript

Why does `Promise<any>` seem to have a "Wozniak free pass for life" in that situation?

Shouldn't it comply to the return type of `Layer` (`Promise<Response>`)?

What is the correct way to enforce `Promise<Response>` as the return type?

```js
type Layer = (req: Request) => Promise<Response>;

type Middleware = (next: Layer) => Layer;

export const json: Middleware = (next: Layer) => async (req: Request) => {
  const res = await next(req);

  if (res.headers.get('Content-Type') === 'application/json') {
    const data = await res.json();

    return data; // -> Type "any" - No TS error, why ??
  }

  return res; // -> Type "Response" - All good
};
```

Answer (score 1):

[any](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any) is a way to "opt-out of type checking", essentially means "Treat it as regular javascript. I don't care type-checking for this thing". So `any` is assignable to anything (except [`never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never) as @equt pointed out) and anything is assignable to `any`.

Comment: _`any` is assignable to anything_, but no, `any` cannot be assigned to `never`.

Comment: Ok but how do I disallow returning `data` (`any`...)? Is it possible to get a TS error in that case?

Comment: The best you can do is explicitly declare a type for `data` if you know its shape, or type it `unknown` if you don't know.

Comment: So there is no way to enforce the Layer “contract”? If you implement a Middleware, I want to force to return a Response, and give the User a nice TS error  if trying to return something else

Comment: What if I don’t want to “opt out” 

Comment: "I want to force to return a Response, and give the User a nice TS error if trying to return something else". If by "something else" you mean to include `any`, then no, there is no way to do so AFAIK. This defies the definition of `any`.